# What is the minimum Boost version to compile Boost.Log (as of revision 667)?

Tags: boost, ios4, boost-log

I have sucessfully built some [Boost C++ 1.44.0](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_44_0.html) libraries for iOS 4.3. I now need [Boost.Log v2](http://boost-log.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/boost-log/branches/bleeding-edge/). Boost.Log requires Boost C++ to be built. However, the Boost.Log documentation does not mention any minimal Boost C++ version.

I found scatered on the net that [Boost.Log was sucessfully built with Boost 1.45.0](http://mytechnotebook.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/how-to-build-and-install-boost-log/) but no information was provided if this was compiled for Boost.Log v1 or v2.

**Can anyone shed some light about the Boost C++ library minimum version that should be used to compile Boost.Log v2 (rev 667) ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I should have tried to build Boost.Log (at 667) before asking this question. In the build output, it is explicitly written:

```
./boost/log/detail/prologue.hpp:36:5: error: #error Boost.Log: **Boost version 1.48 or later is required**
```

Therefore, Boost.Log v2 (at revision 667) requires Boost 1.48.0 minimum.